# How to use inheritance in jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an abstract class address, and two classes that inherit from class address..

classA and classB.

So I found in google the annotation `@xmlSeeAlso` I used this, but I don´t know if it´s correct...

Because the stackTrace prints this error

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 11 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "bairro"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getBairro()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.bairro
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "cep"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getCep()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.cep
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "codigoMunicipio"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getCodigoMunicipio()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.codigoMunicipio
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "codigoPais"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getCodigoPais()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.codigoPais
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "complemento"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getComplemento()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.complemento
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "logradouro"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getLogradouro()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.logradouro
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "municipio"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getMunicipio()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.municipio
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "numero"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getNumero()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.numero
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "pais"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getPais()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.pais
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "telefone"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getTelefone()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.telefone
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
Class has two properties of the same name "UF"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getUF()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.UF
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at nfeProc.Teste.main(Teste.java:15)
```

So what´s wrong?

Comment: I suppose you have @XmlRootElement at `ClassA` and `ClassB`? Then the inheritance shouldn't matter at all (ie, JAXB should just include the fields of the superclass w/o further configuration)

Comment: `@XmlRootElement(name = "enderDest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EnderecoDestinatario extends Endereco {

} 

@XmlRootElement(name = "enderEmit")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EnderecoEmitente extends Endereco {

}
`

Comment: Can you post what `ClassA` and `ClassB` look like.  Here is a link to some articles I have written about JAXB and inheritance:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Inheritance

Comment: The code is above your post, i called `classA` and `classB` because my own classes have some portuguese words...

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan can you answer my post? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> put my code in pastebin.. To explain for you, my classes emitente and
>   destinatario have a field with a endereco (adress) from from
>   enderecoEmitente and enderecoDestinario and they extends from Endereco
>   http://pastebin.com/db0M3rG5

Using your code on paste bin all I had to do was add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to the`Endereco` to get everything to work correctly (since that class has annotated fields).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Endereco {
```

---

### Problem

The problem you are encountering isn't related to inheritance but to the fact that you have annotated the field instead of the property.  By default a JAXB implementation will treat public properties and annotated fields as mapped (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html), this is causing the conflict in your use case:

```
Class has two properties of the same name "pais"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.getPais()
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco.pais
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.Endereco nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente.endereco
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.emit.Emitente nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe.emitente
        at nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.infNFe.InfNFe nfeProc.NFe.NFe.infNFe
        at nfeProc.NFe.NFe
        at private nfeProc.NFe.NFe nfeProc.NFeProc.nfe
        at nfeProc.NFeProc
```

### Solution

The solution is to either annotate the `get` method (or `set` method), or annotate the field and specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the class or package level.

### JAXB & Inheritance

I have written a lot about JAXB and inheritance, you may find the following helpful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Inheritance

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i didn´t understand...

I´m using the annotation `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` in every classes...

So i made a test and put in the 2 concret classes these methods and i didn´t got this error, and i understood why..

The two concret classes are using by inheritance the same abstract class so i got this error, now i don´t know how to correct...

Comment: @user2283439 - Can you post your Java model that produces the exception that you are seeing?

Comment: I put my code in pastebin..

To explain for you, my classes `emitente` and `destinatario` have a field with a `endereco` (adress) from from `enderecoEmitente` and `enderecoDestinario` and they extends from `Endereco`

http://pastebin.com/db0M3rG5

Comment: @user2283439 - I updated my answer with what you need to fix the error.

Comment: i want to know if i need to put in the concrete classes `@XmlAcessorType`? They don´t have any atributes

Comment: @user2283439 - Subclasses inherit the access type from the super class.  Also if the subclasses don't have any fields/properties it wouldn't matter what there access type is.